# When I empty my Cart entity Order emptied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Service
public class PurchaseServiceImpl implements PurchaseService {

@Autowired
private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@Autowired
private CartService cartService;


@Override
public void placeOrder(PlaceOrderRequest placeOrderRequest) {
    Customer customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(placeOrderRequest.getCustomerId());
    Cart cart = customer.getCart();

    if (cart == null || cart.getProducts().isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cart is empty. Cannot be ordered.");
    }

    Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    purchase.setCarts(List.of(cart));
    purchase.setTotalPrice(cart.getTotalPrice());
    purchase.setCustomer(customer);
    customer.getPurchases().add(purchase);
    this.purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
    this.customerService.addCustomer(customer);


    this.cartService.emptyCart(cart.getId());
}
```

As you see I created a new List object and I added current cart instance for `purchase.setCarts`. Even though when I call `cartService.emptyCart` that emptied `purchase.getCarts` too. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you set the carts for the purchase using `purchase.setCarts(List.of(cart))`, you are actually passing a reference to the same `cart` object that is retrieved from the customer's cart. So, when you later call `this.cartService.emptyCart(cart.getId())`, it empties the same cart object that is referenced by the purchase.

In Java, objects are passed by reference, which means when you pass an object to a method, you're passing a reference to the actual object in memory, not a copy of it. So any changes made to that object within the method will affect the original object outside the method as well.

To avoid this behavior, you should create a copy of the cart object before setting it to the purchase, so that changes made to the original cart object do not affect the cart object associated with the purchase. You can do this by creating a new instance of the cart object and copying the relevant attributes over.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public void placeOrder(PlaceOrderRequest placeOrderRequest) {
    Customer customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(placeOrderRequest.getCustomerId());
    Cart inDbCart = customer.getCart();

    if (inDbCart == null || inDbCart.getProducts().isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cart is empty. Cannot be ordered.");
    }

    Cart cart = new Cart();
    cart.setTotalPrice(inDbCart.getTotalPrice());
    cart.setProductCount(inDbCart.getProductCount());
    cart.setProducts(inDbCart.getProducts());


    List<Cart> carts = new ArrayList<>();
    carts.add(cart);

    Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    purchase.setTotalPrice(cart.getTotalPrice());
    purchase.setCarts(carts);
    purchase.setCustomer(customer);
    customer.getPurchases().add(purchase);
    this.purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
    this.customerService.addCustomer(customer);


    this.cartService.emptyCart(inDbCart.getId());
}
```

I did this but the result is still the same. @Bubu Tripathy